# When i click another cell with different value, the back color become black in DataGridView textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, textbox

I made a code for textbox in the DataGridView with eventhandler.

The problem is when I click another cell with different value, the back color of the cell become black.

for example: i have this data in DataGridView

1   1000

2   2000

3   2000

when I click for the 1000, i went well. after that, I click the 2000, the back color for the current cell is black. But, after that if i click the other 2000, the back color become white again.

So, if the value in the highlighted cell is changed, it makes the back color become black.

Is there anybody can help me solve this one?

[image: err]
This is the code for the textbox.

```
    private void dgvSJ_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvSJ.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 10)
        {
            TextBox tx = e.Control as TextBox;              
            tx.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tx_TextChanging);
        }
    }

    void tx_TextChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rowIndexCell = dgvSJ.CurrentRow.Index;
        if (dgvSJ.Rows[rowIndexCell].Cells[10].EditedFormattedValue != null && dgvSJ.CurrentRow.Cells[10].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() != "")
        {
            dgvSJ.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value = string.Format(GlobalVar.PriceFormat, Convert.ToDouble(dgvSJ.CurrentRow.Cells[10].EditedFormattedValue));   ![enter image description here][1]            

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about the selection/highlight color? Change that in your Appearance control panel...

Comment: i already set it with another color which is not black. but it always change to black

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BackColor property to change the background color of the text control to blend into the color scheme of your forms.

XAML

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,165,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="Red" />
```

C#

```
var tbox = new TextBox(){Background = color};
```

Comment: This is not a WPF question. WinForms doesn't use XML.

Answer (score 0):

Use a richTextBox opposed to just a standard textbox as it allows you to change the selection color of the richTextBox (as opposed to the cell as you are doing above.)

```
private void dgvSJ_EditingControlShowing(object sender,   DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvSJ.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 10)
    {
        RichTextBox rtx = e.Control as RichTextBox ; 
        rtx.SelectionColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        rtx.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tx_TextChanging);
    }
}
```